# C11 atomic_load/store and volatile qualifier

Tags: c, concurrency, atomic

Why does the parameter in the C11 `atomic_load`/`atomic_store` functions has the `volatile` qualifier? As it is well established that `volatile` is useless for concurrency use cases (e.g. [1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming), [2](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/CON01-CPP.+Do+not+use+volatile+as+a+synchronization+primitive)).

```
atomic_load( const volatile A* obj );
void atomic_store( volatile A* obj , C desired);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your assumption is false, `volatile` is not useless, it is just not sufficient, which is a different thing.

The interfaces that you cite, *must* have `volatile` qualification, since otherwise they wouldn't work for objects that are such qualified.

Now `volatile` is a difficult subject for C11, because there is currently debate if it is only effective if the object itself is `volatile` qualified or only the current type through which it is accessed. But what is sure, is that the rules for `_Atomic` objects here are not much different than for other objects. So if you'd have a non-`volatile` access that isn't also modifying, the compiler could optimize that access out and rely on a previously known value.

The only such operation that you can do with an `_Atomic` is evaluating it:

```
_Atomic size_t counter = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);

++counter;         // safe: sequential consistency
...
printf("counter: %zu\n", counter); // may use some previous value
...
printf("counter: %zu\n", atomic_load(&counter)); // should use actual value
```

Now the "should" here is because of the different interpretations about `volatile` that I mentioned above. If you want to be sure that no optimization of loads takes place, you should always also declare your `_Atomic` objects `volatile`. It can't hurt much, but may help in some corner cases.

Answer (score -2):

Semantically atomic operations imply there are multiple concurrent threads accessing the variable value. That is what `volatile` specifier is for.

Both references you have provided are very questionable and not generally applicable (as usual in SW engineering). If you have data, that can be concurrently accessed/modified in the software, it has to be `volatile`.

There are use cases, where `volatile` is absolutely necessary: kernel drivers. You can't let compiler optimize access to memory areas, that are mapped to devices.

There are a lot of programming paradigms that are based on `volatile`. For example, normal critical sections/mutexes use `volatile` variables for quick locking and fallback to signals/events/etc only when quick locking fails.

Comment: Shared variables across threads do not *have* to be `volatile`. The use of `volatile` is generally not related to multi-threading. `volatile` means that the object's value can be changed without the control of the implementation, and as such, the compiler refrains from performing access optimizations across sequence points (although they are allowed between sequence points). This is why it is useful for driver programming, but its relation to multi-threading is nonexistent. Shared variables across threads need to be synchronized with mutexes or similar locking primitives.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves synchronization across variables doesn't eliminate optimization. Example is loop: if you have a loop exit variable, and it is not volatile, the compiler may optimize out access to it altogether.